# Intersection of vectors within a same list

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors with character strings:

```
lst <- list(v1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), v2 = c("B", "C", "D", "E"), v3 = c("C", "D", "E", "F")
```

How can I get a new vector that includes only those character strings that intersect each vector. E.g. in this case

```
out <- c("C", "D")
```

A solution with `lapply` would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest function to use would be `Reduce`. Try

```
Reduce(intersect, lst)
```

That's basically the same as

```
# data
x <- list(A, B, C)

# these are equivalent
Reduce(intersect, x)
intersect(intersect(A, B), C)
```

Comment: Thanks! No `lapply` needed after all.:)